# Blazor Wasm: NavigateToLogout and passing extra parameters

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly, msal

According to the docs, you can use an `InteractiveRequestOptions` instance to pass additional parameters during the login. Is there a way to do something similar during the logout process (in this case, I'm interested in setting the `logout_hint` parameter so that the user is automatically logged out without seeing the "pick user dialog".

Thanks.

Comment: did you see this : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42580

Comment: Hello. yes. but it will only work for the login (hints seem to be ignored for the logout operation)